# htmlentities | htmlspecialchars значение флага

Tags: php

Смотрю мануал, вижу такие флаги

```
ENT_SUBSTITUTE
ENT_DISALLOWED
```

Объясните в чем разница принципиальная, из мана я толком ничего не понял

Comment: ENT_SUBSTITUTE Заменяет некорректные кодовые последовательности символом замены Юникода U+FFFD в случае использования UTF-8 и &#FFFD; при использовании другой кодировки, вместо возврата пустой строки.
ENT_DISALLOWED Заменяет неверные коды символов для заданного типа документа символом замены юникода U+FFFD (UTF-8) или &#FFFD; (при использовании другой кодировки) вместо того, чтобы оставлять все как есть. Это может быть полезно, например, для того, чтобы убедиться в формальной правильности XML-документов со встроенным внешним контентом.

Comment: класс! только я это читал в мануале и текстовка то одинаковая у этих флагов, отличие в конце, но оно весьма странное

Comment: @ChromeChrome, понятней не стало :D

Comment: Так ты попробуй забить  в переменную строку с разными символами и переключай флаги и смотри что выдаст

Comment: @MaximPro, вероятно различие в этом `При наличии во входном параметре string недопустимой последовательности символов в заданной кодировке encoding будет возвращена пустая строка, если не установлены флаги ENT_IGNORE или ENT_SUBSTITUTE.`  Тут нет речи про `ENT_DISALLOWED`.

Comment: @Visman хрень какая-то тогда, идиотизм

Answer (score 2):

При использовании флага `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` некорретные последовательности, которые нельзя рассматривать как UTF-8 символы, будут заменяться на FFFD, при использовании `ENT_DISALLOWED` будет возвращаться пустая строка:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(htmlspecialchars("a\x80b", ENT_SUBSTITUTE)); // string(5) "a�b"
var_dump(htmlspecialchars("a\x80b", ENT_DISALLOWED)); // string(0) ""
```

Comment: кстати а что значит "некорретные последовательности"?

Comment: и еще в мануале написано что при флаге `ENT_DISALLOWED` заменяются некорректные последовательности, а в вашем примере этого не происходит...что-то тут не так

Comment: @MaximPro Символы UTF-8 имеют определенную структуру, если это однобайтный символ, первый бит в нем равен 0, в двухбайтном символе первые три бита первого байта равны 110  и т.д. можно посмотреть в с стандарте префиксы для трех, четырех, пяти и шести байтных символов. Если вдруг оказывается, что у вас после очередного байта нет нужного префикса, например, очередной байт начинается не с 0-го бита, а 1-ного, символ считается битым и не может быть интерпретирован как UTF-8 символ (часто такие символы получаются когда русский символ, состоящий из двух байт режется пополам).

Comment: @MaximPro Мануал или переведен криво или в нем ошибка, так как там написано почти одно и тоже про два разных флага, обеспечивающих работу в двух разных режимах - замены битого символа и возврата пустой строки в случае нахождения битого символа.

Answer (score 1):

Просто пример, для большей наглядности:

```
echo htmlspecialchars("<\x80The End\xef\xbf\xbf>", ENT_HTML5 | ENT_DISALLOWED | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');
\\ <�The End�>

echo htmlspecialchars("<\x80The End\xef\xbf\xbf>", ENT_HTML5 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');
\\ <�The End>

echo htmlspecialchars("<\x80The End\xef\xbf\xbf>", ENT_HTML5 | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8');
\\ пустая строка
```

Comment: Насчет |, проясните мне ситуацию, а то мне всегда казалось что это логический оператор или, хотя он пишется как || ... я конечно знаю что есть поразрядный оператор или и пишется он именно как |
Короче объясните мне как в данном контексте это работает
P.S Извините за оффтоп

Comment: @MaximPro, http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Ну я понял это все таки поразрядная операция или, но расскажите мне по какому принципу здесь будет выбран тот или иной флаг

Comment: @MaximPro, `выбран тот или иной флаг` тут не `или`, тут `суммирование` всех флагов прописанных в функции.

Comment: я знаю что это суммирование, но операция называется `или`...ну возьмем ваш первый пример, это будет значить что в качестве 2ого аргумента будут одновременно исполняться 3 флага? `ENT_HTML5, ENT_DISALLOWED, ENT_SUBSTITUTE`

Comment: @MaximPro, все три одновременно, так как при `|` в результате включаются биты включенные хотя бы в одной константе.

Comment: понятно, я провел тесты (вывел эти константы, перевел в двоичную систему и сложил (|) как вы говорили все сложилось то есть суммарное число вышло 10111000) кстати для небольшой статистики напишу здесь чтобы было: `ENT_HTML5 - 48 - 110000, 
ENT_DISALLOWED - 128 - 10000000, ENT_SUBSTITUTE - 8 - 1000
(ENT_HTML5 | ENT_DISALLOWED | ENT_SUBSTITUTE) - 184 - 10111000`